# Keycloak: I can't add custom user attribute into the token?

Tags: keycloak

My users has a `birthDate` attribute:

[image]

I created a mapper in client:

[image]
[image]

Yet it can't be seen in access token:

```
{
  "exp": 1646589516,
  "iat": 1646589216,
  "jti": "7cee1468-8d80-4f14-a118-b07477c1e1e7",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/...",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "f:fd2a5a5a-c7a0-4e74-81a8-916a85885f98:...",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "...",
  "session_state": "efce7a63-2a8f-438d-b4a1-f5d979a00c81",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "sid": "efce7a63-2a8f-438d-b4a1-f5d979a00c81",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "..."
}
```

Can it happen that the keycloak caching somewhere? (I cleared the caches at `Realm` --> `Caches`)

I am desperate... Every tutorial does this and it is not working for me.

Update: I could test it on a server that is remote and it is working. Where the hell the keycloak is caching and screwing me?

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Update2: deleted the keycloak & reinstalled so start from 0:

1. created realm: ep
2. created client: ep
   [image: 3)]
3. Here we can see the user has an attribute `birthDate` with value `my-custom-birth-date`:
   [image]
4. I go `Clients` --> `ep` client --> `Mappers` and create a mapper like this:

[image]

5. `Clients` --> `ep` --> `Client Scopes` --> `Evaluate` --> `Evaluate` button we can see that the `birthDate` can be found there (last row, also the default `birthdate` can be seen):

[image]

6. If I evaluate on the user `P...o` then you can see the access token does not contains the `birthDate` attribute:

[image]

7. If I use postman to request a token for this user, the access_token looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Still missing the attribute `birthDate`.

I repeated every action I did above and in the remote keycloak the attribute can be seen (the last one on the image):

[image]

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------`

So I found the problem:

Here is my keycloak folder and the path to it:

[image]

I copied the `data` folder to here thinking I won't need to recreate the realm/client/etc:

[image]

Whenever I reinstalled the keycloak, I deleted the `keycloak-17.0.0` folder and reinstalled to the same place:

[image]

After I deleted both `data` and `keycloak-17.0.0` and recreate the realm/client/mappers/etc, it is working perfectly...

No idea why did the keycloak checked for configurations/settings/caches a folder above in the tree...

Comment: Can we assume that you've confirmed that you aren't having things like extra spaces, that you've tried other mapper types (like hard-coded claims), that you've confirmed that you aren't testing with the wrong client ID, that you aren't mixing realms that aren't related? We can't confirm all this with information that you masked...

Comment: I literally did the same in the remote keycloak and it did work.

Comment: Also a couple of hours ago it worked... I could add a complete JSON object to it. Must be some kind of caching...

Comment: OK. I get it. But this is the spot where we need to slow down and effectively suppose the software is not wrong, that we're probably missing something minor. It's very likely that "the same thing" differs slightly from what you tried locally. In my experience, KC does not cache this. If you want us to double-check with you, you'll need to add a full screen shot (with address bar and side panel view), the full token without removing issuer or client values, etc, although you can change names.

Comment: Well, I started from 0. Reinstalled keycloak and same result. I updated the post.

Comment: Also did the same on remote keycloak and it works fine. Looks like a cache...

Comment: Do you know why the token has `account` as `aud` instead of `ep`?

Comment: I have no idea. In the keycloak where it works, also the `aud` is `account`.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this locally. Since you reinstalled KC, it can't be a caching thing. What's the version you're using?

Comment: 17.0.0 Keycloak Quarkus

Comment: Well, I found the problem... When I extract the `keycloak-17.0.0.zip` the keycloke will be found in `.\keycloak-17.0.0\keycloak-17.0.0\ ` and here can be found the `bin/conf/data/providers/theme/...` folders and files. when I first reinstalled I copied the `data` to `.\keycloak-17.0.0` so it could be found as `.\keycloak-17.0.0\data`. Then when I reinstalled the keycloak I had a folder structure like this: `.\keycloak-17.0.0\keycloak-17.0.0` and `.\keycloak-17.0.0\data`. This b.tch was caching from here because now that I deleted the whole `.\keycloak-17.0.0` folder so `data` too,now it works

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Ah... I was trying to figure this out as I did an installation and created realm, client, and user, and all worked as expected. But of course I had to assume your reinstall was clean. Good to know you're sorted.

Comment: Now I just wanna know why did the keycloak that can be found in the `.\keycloak\keycloak` folder ran a scan on `.\keycloak` folder :). I added some screenshots in the original post. Maybe has a `@ComponentScan("keycloak-17.0.0")`  on a class...